# How to truncate LISTAGG() in Redshift to prevent overflow

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to concatenate a string from multiple rows in Redshift.

I'm using LISTAGG() which works great until the concatenated string reaches the limit: 
Amazon Invalid operation: Result size exceeds LISTAGG limit
Details:

```
SELECT        LISTAGG(string,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY string DESC) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS string_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes whenever you exceed a string(varchar) size of 65535 bytes on Redshift which is the Max.
Link - [AWS DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-char-or-character)
[image]
Creating another layer above it while using `SUBSTRING()` will do the needful.

Suppose I have this Data -

[image]

So now when i run the query -

```
select distinct listagg(hint,',') WITHIN group (order by id desc) over (PARTITION by Name ) as all_hints from dev.gp_test20200619;
```

I get the following result -

[image]

i.e the length is -> `20`

Now suppose i want the length not to exceed 16, then -

QUERY -

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(all_hints,1,16), length(all_hints) as orignal_length, length(SUBSTRING(all_hints,1,16)) as new_length_using_substring
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT listagg(hint,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY id DESC) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS all_hints
      FROM dev.gp_test20200619)
```

Your result -

[image]

Comment: Did you actually test this query with a large enough data set to exceed Redshift's 65,535 limit? It's not working for me.

Comment: this wont work because it is creating the listagg anyways and then truncating it. The question is, how to create a listagg already truncated to avoid overflow.

Comment: I've been pondering this for a few weeks @SergioPolimante and haven't found an answer for redshift. Oracle has an 'overflow' arg for the listagg, nothing similar in redshift